# Team Fortress 2 displays black screen on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: graphics, games

I can run Team Fortress 2 on Ubuntu 14.04, however the screen is black when I run the game. I can hear the music in the background so the issue seems to be with the graphics.

This is what I got from running it from terminal (the "compile failed" lines are repeated multiple times, I have deleted the repetitions for the sake of brevity):

```
Compile of "vertexlit_and_unlit_generic_vs20" Failed:
Compile of "vertexlit_and_unlit_generic_ps20b" Failed:
Compile of "vertexlit_and_unlit_generic_vs20" Failed:
[...]
Compile of "vertexlit_and_unlit_generic_vs20" Failed:
Compile of "vertexlit_and_unlit_generic_ps20b" Failed:
Unable to remove /home/turtlekicks/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Team Fortress 2/tf/textwindow_temp.html!
Game removed: AppID 440 "Team Fortress 2", ProcID 2426 
pid 2425 != 2422, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/friends"
[0419/145450:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
```

Also, here is the output from `GLXinfo`:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info,
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig,
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info,
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info,
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa Project
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on i915 (chipset: 945GM)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-1eac3ae 2015-04-18 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels,
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage,
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_texture,
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex,
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location,
    GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions,
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow,
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object,
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel,
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays,
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata,
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind,
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query,
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite,
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex,
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects,
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shadow,
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression,
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle,
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra,
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding,
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader,
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev,
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers,
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_EXT_abgr,
    GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate,
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract,
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_instanced,
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit,
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil,
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters,
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal,
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color,
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap,
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D,
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc,
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle,
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_vertex_array,
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays,
    GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug,
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture,
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_light_max_exponent,
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_primitive_restart,
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4,
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format,
    GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp,
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel (git-1eac3ae 2015-04-18 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5,
    GL_APPLE_texture_max_level, GL_EXT_blend_minmax,
    GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, GL_EXT_draw_buffers, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range,
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra,
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1,
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888,
    GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, GL_EXT_unpack_subimage,
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_NV_draw_buffers,
    GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, GL_NV_read_buffer, GL_OES_EGL_image,
    GL_OES_EGL_image_external, GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture,
    GL_OES_depth24, GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_element_index_uint,
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer,
    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_stencil8,
    GL_OES_surfaceless_context, GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_npot,
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object

72 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x020 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x021 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ca 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0cb 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0cc 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0cd 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0ce 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0cf 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0da 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0db 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0dc 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0dd 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0de 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0df 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0e0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0e2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0e4 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0e6 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e7 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0e8 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0e9 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ea 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0eb 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ec 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ed 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0ee 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ef 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0f0 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f1 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0f2 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f3 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0f4 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0f6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0f8 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0f9 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0fa 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0fb 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0fc 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0fd 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0fe 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ff 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x100 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x101 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x102 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x103 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x104 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x105 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x106 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x107 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x108 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x109 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x10a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x10b 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x10c 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x10d 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x10e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x05d 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

108 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x05e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x05f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x060 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x061 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x062 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x063 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x064 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x065 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x066 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x067 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x068 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x069 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x06a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x06c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x06e 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x070 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x071 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x072 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x073 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x074 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x075 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x076 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x077 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x078 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x079 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x07a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x07c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x07e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x080 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x081 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x082  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x083  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x084  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x085  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x086  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x087  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x088  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x089  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08a  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08b  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08c  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08d  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08e  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x090  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x091  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x092  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x093  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x094 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x095 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x096 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x098 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x099 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x09a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09b 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x09c 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x09e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0a0 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a1 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0a2 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a3 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0a4 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0a6 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a7 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a8 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a9 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0aa 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ab 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ac 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ad 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ae 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0af 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b2 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b3 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b4 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b5 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b6 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b7 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b8  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b9  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ba  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bb  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0bc  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bd  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0be  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bf  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0c0  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c1  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0c2  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c3  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0c4  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c5  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0c6  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c7  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0c8  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c9  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh,and the screen is black and the music is still playing in the background.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I fix this??
I tried to reinstall the drivers then the error glgeterror comes back,how????